# Is “denn dadurch” a mistake?

Tags: preposition, conjunction, pronominal-adverb

I am correcting a German text for my B2 preparation and I was wondering if this is is considered a mistake:

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, **denn dadurch** hätte ich die Möglichkeit, alle per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

Is it correct? Isn’t one or the other redundant?
Also, there is another mistake in the text (the joy of exams …), so don’t mind that.

Comment: No, it is perfectly fine. The English translation would be "*because doing so, I…*".

Comment: Bei dem Text "denn dadurch hätte ich die Möglichkeit, **alle** per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen." ist unklar worauf sich **alle** bezieht, das könnte falsch sein.

Comment: Big factual error, though: It should read _Lastschrift oder Überweisung_. Cheques are as good as dead.

Comment: By the way, in this case, a semicolon can be used instead of a comma before _denn_.

Comment: @chirlu: Shecks mögen als Zahlungsmittel so gut wie tot sein, als Wort sind  sie es noch lange nicht. Weißt Du wie alt der Text ist, aus dem das stammt? Sind Texte über Pferdedroschken mit diesen untergegangen?

Comment: @Karl: Auf 'Rechnungen' wahrscheinlich, oder?

Comment: @user unknown ,  möglich, aber ohne gegebenen Kontext? Oder wenn vorher steht: _Ich muß das ganze Zeug bezahlen._ ; dann wäre *alles* korrekt.

Comment: *Alle* need not even be wrong if the sentences before talk about all the people s/he has to pay. Think the gardener, the butler, the bicycle repair man …

Comment: @user unknown: Es war teilweise scherzhaft gemeint, weil mir schon klar ist, daß es bei Sprachprüfungen nicht darum geht, inhaltlich fragwürdige Aussagen zu korrigieren. (Manchmal geht es um Negationen, aber schon das ist gefährlich, wenn die gewählten Beispiele nicht super-eindeutig sind.) Aber typischerweise benutzen diese Prüfungen tatsächlich aktuelle Texte, schon um sich nicht mit dem Sprachwandel seit der Pferdedroschkenzeit herumschlagen zu müssen.

Comment: @Karl: Ich bestreite nicht, das "alles" falsch sein könnte, aber wenn es auch richtig sein könnte, halte ich es nicht für angebracht, darüber zu spekulieren.

Comment: @chirlu: Ich habe noch kein Vorbereitungsmaterial für eine B2-Prüfung gesehen, um Deine Aussage für gänzlich abwegig zu halten. Der fehlende Kontext tut m.M.n. nichts zur Sache, weil ja aktuelle Texte ganz zweifellos die 20er, 50er und 90er Jahre behandeln können.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither *denn* nor *dadurch* is redundant. TLDR version: *denn dadurch* translates to *for by that*.

Let’s see what happens if we leave either one out. First we drop *denn*:

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, dadurch hätte ich die Möglichkeit, alles per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

This is two main clauses in a row. You can do this, even without joining them by *und*, but then you should separate them by a semicolon. (Or by a full stop/period, of course.) If you really want a comma, you need to transform the second sentence into a relative clause:

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, wodurch ich die Möglichkeit hätte, alles per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

That’s just like in English, except in German the word order in a relative clause is different.

Now we drop *dadurch* instead

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, denn hätte ich die Möglichkeit, alles per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

This is not even grammatical. German *denn* is a bit of a false friend because the German word for *then* is actually *dann*. (Even worse: In antiquated German you can use *denn* for comparisons, in the sense of *than*. So the roles are precisely reversed!) Without *dadurch*, we need *dann*, not *denn*:

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, dann hätte ich die Möglichkeit, alles per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

But this is still not quite correct. As in the case of dropping *then*, we now have two main clauses in a row. We should separate them by a semicolon, join them by *und*, or just use a full stop.

Or another way of fixing this would be to join them by *denn*:

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, denn dann hätte ich die Möglichkeit, alles per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

You might think that *denn dann* feels as weird as a duplicated word, but it doesn’t. In fact, it’s a very common combination of words that translates to English *for then*. And indeed, the standard meaning of *denn* is *because* or *for* (the one that means the same as *because*).

In your sentence, *dadurch* isn’t very good style. It feels a bit colloquial here because it’s not clear whether you mean *durch das Konto* (colloquial because standard would be *mit dem Konto*) or *durch den Besitz eines Kontos* (colloquial because the noun this refers to never appeared explicitly). It would be better to use *damit*, standing for *mit dem Konto*. So this would be slightly better:

> Am liebsten wäre mir ein Girokonto, denn damit hätte ich die Möglichkeit, alles per Scheck oder Banküberweisung zu bezahlen.

Except, of course, for the idea to use cheques. In German-speaking countries, you would normally only encounter a cheque if someone wants to annoy you or doesn’t want you to receive the money. (In the last decade I have seen precisely one cheque while living in Germany and Austria. It was some kind of bonus from my health insurer. I am sure I wasn’t the only recipient who didn’t cash it. I had no idea how to do that given that my bank doesn’t even have a normal branch in Berlin. The effort of figuring this out simply wasn’t worth the 30 Euros or whatever it was.)

Comment: I'd rather say it translates to "because with that" or "because by using that".

Comment: *With that* is better translated as *damit*. In the gory details I explained why this would be better in the German sentence. I chose the more literal English translation *by that* precisely because it has a very similar problem. (The difference is that in English it's also slightly non-standard, but definitely not colloquial.)

Comment: As to *for* vs. *because*, maybe it's caused by my déformation professionnelle as a mathematician, but to me *for* sounds slightly better than *because*, or at least slightly closer to the German sentence. When translating educated speech, I tend to translate *weil* by *because* (inevitably) and *denn* by *for*.

Comment: Auch Du scheinst es für ausgeschlossen zu halten, dass es einen Satz davor gibt, in dem von Rechnungen die Rede ist, die alle per Girokonto bezahlt werden könnten und zu unterstellen, dass Texte immer die Gegenwart behandeln müssen.

Comment: How lucky I was that 1) my health insurance gave me a 150 € bonus and 2) I knew *exactly* where the branch of my bank was (even though the branch has shut down, now).

Comment: I'm really really curious why insurance companies in general are so fond of cheques and noone else uses them (in G). They all know how to use electronic fund transfers to get their premiums and in the case of health insurance, they don't even have to request that, but instead get the premium with zero effort from my employer. So is it really that they count on people not cashing those cheques? There should be a law against that -.-

Comment: @userunknown: Ich hab den aktuellen Kontext mit einbezogen, und der ist ein Sprachkurs zur Vorbereitung auf B2. Es ist aus meiner Sicht fast ausgeschlossen, dass da Aufsätze über den Alltag des frühen oder mittleren 20. Jahrhunderts zu schreiben oder fehlerhafte Texte aus dieser Zeit zu korrigieren sind.

Comment: @HansAdler: Ich weiß ja nicht wann für Dich das mittlere 20. Jahrhundert endet, aber ich habe nach Mitte der 90er noch einige Schecks bekommen.

Answer (score 6):

No, *denn dadurch* is perfectly fine.
However *alle* is probably wrong since nothing is referred (think *all of them* without knowing what *them* is). You probably want *alles* meaning *everything*.

Source: German is my mother language.

Comment: The only question is whether "durch" is the right preposition. Durch ein Girokonto? I'm not sure.

Comment: @CarstenS Durch den Besitz des Girokontos.

Comment: @Robert, das steht da aber nicht.

Comment: Im Satz davor könnte etwas von Rechnungen stehen. Das erscheint mir wesentlich plausibler, als alles per Girokonto zu bezahlen.